# Using INSERT INTO without concurrent access for SELECT in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-into

I have an app that requires a single instance of a task to be run. In order to check whether a current instance of the task is already running, i check the status of the task. If the task has a combination of one or more of those statuses, then it knows the task is already running and should skip the task for now. These tasks can be called from multiple places so i could have a hundred or so calls for the task to be run in a minute.

I wanted someone to do a sanity check on the SQL that i am using and tell me if it will take care of the locking correctly and allow only one instance of the task to run.

The SQL:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT LogID FROM Log2 T3 WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
  WHERE T3.Param2 = ? AND T3.Action = ? AND T3.LogID NOT IN 
    (SELECT T2.LogID FROM Log2 T1 WITH (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK), Log2 T2 WITH
      (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK) WHERE T1.Action IN (?,?,?,?,?) AND T2.Action = ? 
      AND T1.Param3=T2.Param3 AND T1.Param2 = ?)) 
  INSERT INTO Log2 WITH (UPDLOCK) (LogID, Action, EventDateTime) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

The ? represent values that will be inserted at run time.

Will the above query make sure that only one record is inserted at any one time and the locking hints are correctly placed ?
At the moment the query seems to be behaving properly - i just don't want to make the app live and find out that the query does not lock other threads out correctly and that in turn will allow multiple tasks to be run at the same time (as multiple records will be written out and the polling app will pick up 2 records at he same time).

Thanks

Comment: I think using [`MERGE WITH (HOLDLOCK)`](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx) is the most threadsafe way to achieve this, since the locks from your select need to be released before you proceed to the insert, so there is still a window for a race condition. You should however, [Use Merge with caution](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) as there are edge cases where it is a bit buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to do this is to use either insert or update without the initial select.  You can either have a where clause or a unique constraint to prevent multiple records (and hence tasks).

If two sources try to kick off a process at the exact same millisecond only one of them will succeed and based on the return value of the query know whether to start the task or skip it.

This way you do not have to worry about locking.